# Moodle authentication by external application using java web service

Tags: java, web-services, basic-authentication, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to connect to Moodle using java web service.
What I need to do is, authenticate moodle and save users into it.

Can anyone provide me some sample code in java for authentication? It would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a basic **REST MOODLE Client**  :

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.ProtocolException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;

    /**
     * REST MOODLE Client
     * It's very basic. You'll have to write the JavaObject2POST code.
     *
     */
    public class RestJsonMoodleClient {

        /**
         * Do a REST call to Moodle. Result are displayed in the console log.
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ProtocolException, IOException {

            /// NEED TO BE CHANGED
            String token = "acabec9d20933913f14301785324f579";
            String domainName = "http://www.yourmoodle.com";

            /// REST RETURNED VALUES FORMAT
            String restformat = "xml"; //Also possible in Moodle 2.2 and later: 'json'
                                       //Setting it to 'json' will fail all calls on earlier Moodle version
            if (restformat.equals("json")) {
                restformat = "&moodlewsrestformat=" + restformat;
            } else {
                restformat = "";
            }

            /// PARAMETERS - NEED TO BE CHANGED IF YOU CALL A DIFFERENT FUNCTION
            String functionName = "core_user_create_users";
            String urlParameters =
            "users[0][username]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testusername1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][password]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testpassword1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][firstname]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testfirstname1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][lastname]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testlastname1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][email]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testemail1@moodle.com", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][auth]=" + URLEncoder.encode("manual", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][idnumber]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testidnumber1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][lang]=" + URLEncoder.encode("en", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][theme]=" + URLEncoder.encode("standard", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][timezone]=" + URLEncoder.encode("-12.5", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][mailformat]=" + URLEncoder.encode("0", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][description]=" + URLEncoder.encode("Hello World!", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][city]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testcity1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][country]=" + URLEncoder.encode("au", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][preferences][0][type]=" + URLEncoder.encode("preference1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][preferences][0][value]=" + URLEncoder.encode("preferencevalue1", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][preferences][1][type]=" + URLEncoder.encode("preference2", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[0][preferences][1][value]=" + URLEncoder.encode("preferencevalue2", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[1][username]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testusername2", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[1][password]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testpassword2", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[1][firstname]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testfirstname2", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[1][lastname]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testlastname2", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[1][email]=" + URLEncoder.encode("testemail2@moodle.com", "UTF-8") +
            "&users[1][timezone]=" + URLEncoder.encode("Pacific/Port_Moresby", "UTF-8");

            /// REST CALL

            // Send request
            String serverurl = domainName + "/webservice/rest/server.php" + "?wstoken=" + token + "&wsfunction=" + functionName;
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(serverurl).openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
               "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setUseCaches (false);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                      con.getOutputStream ());
            wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
            wr.flush ();
            wr.close ();

            //Get Response
            InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }
```

for more information please follow the links :

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client#Difference_between_Moodle_versions

http://www.rumours.co.nz/manuals/using_moodle_web_services.htm

https://github.com/mudrd8mz/node-moodle-client

Share and enjoy... :)

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response :) 
Where can I find this token value?

Comment: Create a token :
This feature allows you to create a token for specific user :

1) Settings > Site Administration > Plugins > Web services > Manage tokens
2) Click on Add
3) Select the created user and service
4) Click on Saves changes